# Gzip compression only works when I send some random query string along with my URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, compression, gzip

I have spent like 2 days on this. My website is running on apache web server and I have added all code required to enable gzip compression. Below is the code added in my .htaccess in root directory

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

When I detect gzip compression using a tool gtmetrix or checkgzipcompression on my home page it shows the compression is not enabled. However if I add any random query string to my URL like example.com?v=32123 it shows compression is enabled. This is happening from last 3 days I have tried clearing all cache. I talked to my hosting support and they said gzip is enabled from their side. I'm not sure what I am missing. Please advise.

Comment: Cached by a proxy server, perhaps? Have you checked the Apache access logs? You could also enable deflate logs as described in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html.

Comment: @user2612030 Ah I did not think about proxy server caching. I just checked and the client seems to be using Sucuri Cloudproxy as proxy server. I'll check with him. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you @user2612030 caching at proxy server was indeed the issue. Thanks a lot you saved me some headache!!